# google charts bar chart - very high and low values

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a problem with displaying the low values in my charts.

[image: barchart]

The values for this chart are:

```
total: 210155
reads: 48759
clicks: 9284
hb: 88
sb: 66
spam: 13
```

I need to have a very low first gridline, around a 100.
So I would get 100, 100K 200K.

I tried adding the: hAxis.logScale option, but this didn't work.

Does anybody know how I would go about this?

Comment: Do you want a log scale or a linear scale?

Comment: a log scale! just googled it, really didn't know how to describe my problem.

Comment: and when I add the hAxis.logScale option it doesn't change 1 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the hAxis.logScale working when I changed back to the old google charts instead of the material design charts. The option doesn't seem to be working yet.

I changed this:

```
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart'));
```

To:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart'));
```

And it worked straight away, this did change to look of my chart tho.
[image]

Comment: You should accept your own answer, get the points and others might find it useful.